# Flume use-case - push data from read-only folder to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, rsync, flume-ng

I am looking for a way to push log data from a read-only folder to hdfs using flume. as I know, flume spoolDir needs write access to change the completed file name when done, so I wanted to create a temp folder as a spoolDir and use rsync to copy files to it and then use it as a spoolDir.
but, as much as I know, once the file is changed on the dest folder by flume (myfile.COMPLETED) the rsync process will copy it again, right?
Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative source is the [`ExecSource`](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source). You can run a `tail` command on a single read-only file and start processing the data. Nevertheless, you must have into account this is an unreliable source since there is no way to recover from an error while putting the data into the agent channel.